# SD card won't work

Tags: 14.04, mount, sd-card

My laptop won't detect my SD card nor here at ubuntu or Win10.
So I:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and...

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util   fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1dc78e4a

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3904 MB, 3904897024 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 119168 cylinders, total 7626752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xaea8aaff

Disk /dev/mmcblk0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

So what shall I Do?

I also installed Hardinfo and found at kernel modules I have a Realtek PCI Card Host Driver and somethin called Multimedia Card Block device driver
but I don't know anythign about those.

Comment: If it isn't detected on Windows 10 either, it's almost definitely a hardware issue. Check you BIOS settings, though, as there may be a setting to toggle it on and off.